# Kailash always has a $\frac 34$ chance of winning any game he plays. What is the probability that out of 5 games he plays, he wins $2$ and loses $3$?

Tags: probability, contest-math

Kailash always has a $\frac{3}{4}$ chance of winning any game he plays. What is the probability that out of 5 games he plays, he wins $2$ and loses $3$?

I know the answer is $\frac{45}{512}$, but what are the steps to getting there, and which methods are the quickest?

Comment: It's a classic case of binomial distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Binomial Distributions** are $25\%$ cooler.

The probability of winning 2 games in a row then loosing 3 is $\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^3$.

However, that's one particular order. There are ${5\choose 2}$ permutations of that result.

$$\mathsf P(\text{Answer})= \frac{5!}{2!\,3!}\frac{3^2}{4^5} = \frac{45}{512}$$

Answer (score 4):

Try the binomial distribution:

Experiment: Randomly sample 5 Games

Random Variable $W$: # of $W$inners

Possible Values $w$: 0     1     2     3     4     5

Dichotomous Outcomes: Success = Winner, Failure = Not Winner

Constant Probability: P(Winner) = 0.75

Independence? P(Winner|Any previous Outcomes) = P(Winner) = 0.75

Since random variable is the number of success, this is a binomial experiment with n=5 and p = 0.75.

Now, use binomial tables or

$P(W=2) = \dfrac{5!}{2!(5-2)!} (0.75)^2(1−0.75)^{5−2} $ = $0.08789063 $ = $\dfrac{45}{512} $ = $10 \cdot 0.5625 \cdot 0.015625 $